# ADF (augmented Dickey-Fuller) in JavaScript without a library

Tags: time-series, augmented-dickey-fuller, javascript

ADF (Augmented Dickey-Fuller) test to check if an asset price is stationary or non-stationary using pure JavaScript without any library.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.